# using c++11 with g++ doesn't work on mac

Tags: macos, c++11, g++

I tried to set g++ to compile in c++11. I read that i need to use the flag, -std=c++11, but it's not aviailable at my g++ version(4.2.1), and there's not clear information about updating it. What should i do?

Comment: Hm, what does g++ -v say? My XCode 5.1 g++ reports that it's using g++ 4.2.1 include files, but it sure works with -std=c++11

Comment: Get the current version of [gcc](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Development/Compilers/GCC.shtml) or [Clang/LLVM](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#3.4.2) (or, preferably, both). 4.2.1 is pretty old (released in 2007).

Comment: Up until version 4.6 the compiler didn't recognize the `-std=c++11` option, instead it was called `-std=c++0x`. However, I doubt there is much, if any, C++11 support in version 4.2. You should definitely update to something new, currently it's up to 4.9.1.

Comment: Apple has been masquerading clang as gcc/g++ for a while now. `g++ -std=c++11` should work fine, as it will spawn a new version of clang instead.

Comment: @JerryCoffin How do i do it?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg neither of them works

Comment: Download from one (or both) of the links in my comment, and follow the installation instructions.